# Do I have to have a website in order to have a page on FB?

Tags: plugins, facebook-like

I offered to set up a FB page for our upcoming 30th high school reunion.  I went in and created the page, but cannot seem to figure out how to add the "LIKE" button.  Everything I have read:  Getting Started / Websites https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ as well as the Social Plugins page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ all seem to begin with the assumption that I have a website.  I don't have one.

So my bottom line question is: do I have to CREATE a webpage (outside FB) in order to move ahead with adding the social plugins?

Obviously I am a newbie, have no technical experience but can read and follow directions.
Solutions, O Great Ones?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a page, other users will see a Like button on the page. So, they can like that page and then you can publish posts to it. This is a good way to keep people informed, involved, and engaged.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the plugins are for (to include in html), they are not necessary to use to just have a page.

You might not see the like button because you created it, i'd imagine.

Comment: When I "View page" I don't see a "like" button....is that because I already "liked" it???

Comment: Yes, it is there already.  Duh. Someone please close this.  Sorry to waste your time.....(but i did it!)

Comment: Sorry! at least give me some points for sparking the idea. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a website in order to use the Social Plugins, but it does help. Otherwise, you need permission to use the HTML on websites / pages you don't own but have access to.

E.g. You can ask your school to add the Social Plugins to their existing website that will let students like the fan page you created.